# Random "No Internet" when connected to a working router

Tags: windows, router, laptop, internet, internet-connection

I sometimes get "No Internet" while being connected to my home router with full signal, but other devices connected to it have no Internet access issues (2 phones and 1 more laptop).

I'm using Huawei Matebook X Pro. The router was provided by my ISP and it has no branding on it.

Restarting the router has no effect. I've tried just waiting for about half an hour with no effect. Releasing and renewing IP has no effect.

Rebooting my laptop **always helps**, but I'm wondering what's the root of this problem?

Comment: if rebooting the laptop always helps the issue is very probably on the laptop itself. have you tried to see if there is a newer FW/driver for your network card?

Comment: You'd need to view the router's system log to determine if it's the router or not _(WiFi needs to be set to an actual channel, not "Auto". 2.4Ghz Channel: `1`, `6`, or `11` || 5GHz Channel: highest available, such as `157`)_. **General FYI:** a personal router should **_always_** be used between an ISP provided router & your LAN _(if it's not a modem/router combo - one device housing the modem & router components - ditch it and place your own router in it's place)_, as ISP's retain SSH access to their routers, and due to this, it's a security risk for all downstream data & devices on the LAN.

Comment: @Zina according to device manager, my drivers are up to date.

Comment: @JW0914 I have a modem/router combo. I've set 2.4GHz channel to 11 and 5GHz to highest available that is not DFS. What should I look for in the network logs?

Comment: @JarekDanielak You want a DFS channel, otherwise you'll likely either lose the wifi connection entirely or at best have a subpar connection when interference is detected.  _(DFS allows the seamless transition to another frequency)_. Beyond that, you need to review the router's system logs to determine if the router is the issue, which may not be possible on an ISP-provided router; however, since it is ISP-provided, they will troubleshoot the issue with you and can provide you with a debug firmware image to flash that outputs the system log in a variety of ways for you to view or send to them.